# Cannot Load image in imageView from gallery

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to load an image in an image view from the gallery on the phone and I have
written the code
    java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
Button btnTry , btnAdd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnTry = findViewById(R.id.btnTry);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //The integer argument is a "request code" that identifies your request. When you receive the result Intent,
            // the callback provides the same request code so that your app can properly identify the result and determine how to handle it.

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i ,RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && requestCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
        Uri selectImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathcolumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectImage , filePathcolumn , null , null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathcolumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView ivMemeImage = findViewById(R.id.ivMemeImage);

ivMemeImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}
}
```

when I run the app and hit the add button image does not load in the image view.
and I have given both the read and write permission in the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display your image using your Uri. you only need to do is set your `imageView.setImageUri(selectedImage)`

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
  Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
  your_imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

is this code you have done in android studio?

```
    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && requestCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)
```

it should be

```
    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && requestCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null)
```

Your code should give you compile time error

Comment: whats wrong with my answer? The code given in question is wrong

Answer (score -2):

check out Picasso library .. http://square.github.io/picasso/

load image from a URI into imageview with one line of code:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```